# Insert Time Stamp For New Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a job that is run every night where it needs to update records with a time stamp that is greater than yesterday's date. This way my search table doesn't have to update 200,000+ records.

Currently I have a column name TimeStamp in my table with the current time stamps already in there. I want to insert a time stamp for ONLY NEW ROWS that are imported and I'm a little lost.

Here's what I have so far:

```
ALTER TABLE CustomerMaster
ALTER COLUMN TimeStamp SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Am I on the right path?

Comment: @MarcB are you referring to MySQL's autoupdated timestamps? This is tagged with [sql-server]. Oh, I just noticed that the question was tagged with [mysql] initially...

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerMaster ADD CONSTRAINT df_TimeStamp DEFAULT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FOR [TimeStamp]; `

Comment: @ypercube: argh, yeah. doh... i'll just go slink off into a corner and finish waking up...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, what is the constraint for?  And will there need to be another column created for df_TimeStamp?

Comment: Basically, `DEFAULT` is not a column property, like `NULL` or `IDENTITY`, but a *constraint*. So, rather than altering a column, you add a constraint, as Aaron has shown you.

Comment: @AndriyM, thanks. But can you explain the df_TimeStamp? New to SQL. Looks like another column in the table, but is it just calling for the default?

Comment: It is not another column in the table. It is the name of the constraint, so that you don't end up with a constraint with an awful name like `DF__CustomerM__TimeS__22BB7146`.

Comment: It's just a name you assign to the constraint added. You can learn the syntax in the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx "ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)"). (Yes, it's a big article about all ALTER TABLE variations, you'll need to look for the ADD CONSTRAINT variation's description. Or you could read the entire thing while you are at it.)